# Guice provider that provides the same type in different scopes - circular dependency

Tags: java, generics, guice

I'd like to @RequestScope a class (e.g. Rabbit.class). A simple way to do this would be to annotate the class with @RequestScope, or to add a statement in a module

```
  public void configure(){
    bind(Rabbit.class).in(RequestScope.class)
    ...
  }
```

However, this is a bit of a dangerous change, so I'd like to guard this behavior with an experiment flag. The experiment flag could be different (true or false) for any given request. So the RequestScope'ing must be done in a provider that injects the flag.

```
public class RabbitProvider extends Provider<Rabbit> {

    @Inject
    RabbitProvider(boolean flag, @ThisIsRequestScoped Rabbit requestScopedRabbit, @ThisIsNotRequestScoped Rabbit newRabbit) {
      // save to instance vars
    }

    @Override
    Rabbit get() {
      return flag ? requestScopedAnimal : newAnimal;
    }
}
```

```
  public void configure(){
    bind(Rabbit.class).annotatedWith(ThisIsRequestScoped.class).in(RequestScoped.class);
    bind(Rabbit.class).annotatedWith(ThisIsNotRequestScoped.class);
    bind(Rabbit.class).toProvider(RabbitProvider.class);
  }
```

Not good. Circular dependency:

> Rabbit -> RabbitProvider -> @ThisIsRequestScoped Rabbit -> Rabbit

Both keys @ThisIsNotRequestScoped Rabbit and @ThisIsRequestScoped Rabbit point to Rabbit which points to the provider. Not sure how to fix this circle. Any ideas? Is it even possible to bind a type to a provider that would provide that type in different scopes?

Answer (score 0):

Ah - found a way that works if you have a superclass type.

Suppose Rabbit extends Animal, then: Have all application code inject Animal, bind Animal to the provider, and you can give Rabbit any bindings like an annotated @ThisIsRequestScoped binding. In the provider, since Rabbit is bound to itself implicitly, you can inject it (a new instance would be created, or you can inject @ThisIsRequestScoped Rabbit to grab the request scoped one).